# Appropriate place to store custom properties in Jenkins `config.xml`

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm programmatically generating Jenkins `config.xml` job configuration files, and would like to store/attach some metadata to the XML DOM, to be ignored by Jenkins, but not removed or marked as "Obsolete data". Just simple key/value pairs, things like client tool build date, user, etc.

Where in the XML structure would it be appropriate to put such a thing? I've tried putting it under the `/project/properties` branch, but the data gets culled by the server when I POST the new job. Or is there a plugin that would allow this (I tried the Metadata plugin, but it overwrote my sections)?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I spoke too quickly! The job config updates after my POST, but gets pruned on the next Jenkins build.

For those still wondering about this, I was able to add my custom properties under the root `<project>` tag by POST'ing the updated config.xml. So it looked like this:

```
<project>
...
    <myCustomTag>
        <customProp>foo</customProp>
    </myCustomTag>
...
</project>
```

I combined all of my custom properties under one custom tag to separate them from the rest of the config and avoid accidental name collisions with regular config props.

Jenkins version 2.0